# PyTest-fixtures: Let data persist (Django)

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

I like pytest-django fixtures and use them in my django application.

But from time to time I would like to have data to play around.

Up to now the pytest fixtures are only in the temporary database.

My goal: I would like to have a button in my django-web GUI. If I press the
button a list of my pytest fixtures should get called inside the normal database.

If I try to call the fixtures directly in a django view, I get this message:

```
Failed: Fixture "waiting_for_activation_user" called directly. Fixtures are not meant to be called directly,
but are created automatically when test functions request them as parameters.
See https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html for more information about fixtures, and
https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/deprecations.html#calling-fixtures-directly about how to update your code.
```

Of course I could ignore that the test fixtures exist, and implement the "create test-data" button with the help of the Django ORM method `update_or_create()`. But that's not nice, since
I need to implement the creation of test data twice

Has anybody a solution, so that I need write the code to create test-data only once, and I can use it twice (once for the pytext fixture, once for the button)?

Answer (score 1):

I would extract the part of the fixtures that you want to use within your normal web application into some type of factory module or class. Then write tests against the new part to confirm the factory works as expected.

I would not however try to use the pytest fixture directly within the web application.